# How to add missing IBM Designer builders to Eclipse plugin project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xpages, lotus-notes

I am using Eclipse to create a plugin for XPages. The code compiles fine but I have a bunch of missing builders in the settings of the project:[image]

Is there a way to add these builders to Eclipse ? 
Using the plugin without the builders brings an error on the console like:
*com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: The application /home.nsf requires com.mycorp.myplugin.xsp.library. This library cannot be found.*

That´s why I think that the builders are doing something special to the plugin to get it running on Domino.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or the DDE? I have never seen this builders for Plugin Development in plain Eclipse before (and never missed them).

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Maybe I dont need them, but the only difference between building in Notes and Eclipse should be the builders. When I use the plugin built in Eclipse I get the error that the plugin class cannot be found.
I am doing all these steps only because my plugin isnt compiled in Notes 10.x anymore...I tried everything like https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/058650E080E352178525832B00519D2C no chance. In the update site project I see a process bar with "Building ant script" for a short time when I build the plugin. The very same project could be built in Notes 9.x perfectly

Comment: So why do you not remove the missing builders? From my understanding, these builders are only required to build a XPages application in an NSF.

Comment: https://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/04.11.2019160604KLEKQD.htm?opendocument

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and the very (and brandnew) link to Karsten´s ideas. I will follow the instructions and keep this problem updated !